# Eliminating SQL rows based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT g.new_attempt, c.fullname, c.new_intaketermidname
    , g.new_module, c.new_programmeidname, g.statecodename
    , cp.new_termidname, c.statuscodename, g.new_resultstatusname, g.statuscodename    
FROM [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].[FilteredNew_grade] g 
join [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].New_studentprogress sp on sp.New_studentprogressId = g.new_progressid 
join [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].FilteredContact c on c.contactid = sp.New_ContactId
join [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].[FilteredNew_coursesofprogramme] cp on cp.new_coursesofprogrammeid = g.new_courseid
join [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].FilteredNew_programme p on p.new_programmeid = c.new_programmeid    
where c.statecodename = 'Active' 
and c.statuscodename not in ('Alumni (active)')
and c.fullname = 'Stefanos Chalvatzis'
```

This brings all the grades of that specific student (Failed, Passed), what I would like to do is get only the resits of that student but if the student passed that course at any time during his academic semesters, omit both the resit row and the passed row, is there a way to do this?

For example:

```
new_attempt fullname    new_intaketermidname    new_module  new_programmeidname statecodename   new_termidname  statuscodename  new_resultstatusname    statuscodename
1   Stefanos Chalvatzis 2017-18 / Fall  ΝΟΜ229-GR   LLB Law - Greek Law Inactive    2018-19 / Spring    Registered  Fail    Resit coursework & exam
2   Stefanos Chalvatzis 2017-18 / Fall  ΝΟΜ229-GR   LLB Law - Greek Law Inactive    2018-19 / Spring    Registered  Pass    Completed
```

As you can see here the student had a resit in NOM229 but passed that course in a second attempt - I want my query to omit these 2 lines if the above is the case else display the resit one only (if that course is not found as passed later on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for the example you have provided, using a CTE you can check if a `pass` result exists and if so return no results for that student.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT g.new_attempt, c.fullname, c.new_intaketermidname
        , g.new_module, c.new_programmeidname, g.statecodename
        , cp.new_termidname, c.statuscodename, g.new_resultstatusname, g.statuscodename, c.new_studentid    
    FROM [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].[FilteredNew_grade] g 
    join [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].New_studentprogress sp on sp.New_studentprogressId = g.new_progressid 
    join [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].FilteredContact c on c.contactid = sp.New_ContactId
    join [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].[FilteredNew_coursesofprogramme] cp on cp.new_coursesofprogrammeid = g.new_courseid
    join [NUP_MSCRM].[dbo].FilteredNew_programme p on p.new_programmeid = c.new_programmeid    
    where c.statecodename = 'Active' 
    and c.statuscodename not in ('Alumni (active)')
    --and c.fullname = 'Stefanos Chalvatzis'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte C1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cte C2
    WHERE C2.statuscodename = 'Pass'
    AND C2.new_studentid = C1.new_studentid
);
```